# основы PHP или как посчитать деньги на депозите в Банке

Tags: php

Пытаюсь вычислить, сколько мне понадобится лет и сколько мне будет (сейчас 16), чтобы заработать 1 млн. руб., если положить деньги на депозит на 10% годовых (с капитализацией на 10%), то есть увеличение каждый год на увеличенную сумму

пример кода:

```php
<?php

$deposit = 10000;
$procent=0.1;



for ($age = 16; $age<=100; $age ++){


$deposit = ($deposit*$procent)+$deposit;
$vsego = ($deposit*$procent)+$deposit;


    echo "в {$age} лет мои накопления составят = {$vsego};<br/>";

    if ($vsego > 1000000) {
        echo "Ура лям в банке. Всего потребовалось {$age} лет<br/>";
        break;
    }
}
```

результат вывода:

> в 16 лет мои накопления составят = 12100;
>
> в 17 лет мои накопления составят = 13310;
>
> в 18 лет мои накопления составят = 14641;
>
> ...
>
> в 62 лет мои накопления составят = 970172.33784872;
>
> в 63 лет мои накопления составят = 1067189.5716336;
>
> Ура лям в банке. Всего потребовалось 63 лет

Скрипт считает не правильно. В первый год вместо `11 000 руб` он выдает `12 100 руб`.
Помогите еще понять, как правильно указать количество произведенных действий в цикле: `Всего потребовалось ___ лет`. В моем примере неправильно.

Comment: и не забудьте вычитать 13% из полученного дохода ;)

Comment: @plesser жизненно...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы зачем то дважды просчитываете проценты и в результате показываете состояние счета на следующий год. Чуточку поудалял кода и вроде оно ок

```
<?php

$deposit = 10000;
$procent=0.1;
$start_from = 16;


for ($age = $start_from; $age<=100; $age ++){


$deposit = ($deposit*$procent)+$deposit;


    echo "в {$age} лет мои накопления составят = {$deposit};<br/>\n";

    if ($deposit > 1000000) {
       $need = $age - $start_from;
        echo "Ура лям в банке. Всего потребовалось {$need} лет<br/>\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

на самом деле это все легко проверить. Нужно просто решить уравнение `10000 * 1.1^x = 1000000`. (где ^ - это степень). Это уравнение легко сводиться к `1.1 ^ x = 100` -> `x * ln(1.1) = ln(100)` -> `x = ln(100)/ln(1.1)` x порядка 48 лет.

Посмотрев на это все, можно вывести формулу вида `нужно_лет= ln(конечная_сумма/начальная_сумма)/ln(1+проценты_в_год/100)`.

Comment: Уммм... сначала так и делал, но видимо, что то пошло не так) наверное скобки ($deposit*$procent) не ставил. @KoVadim благодарю . Ниже я указывал еще вопрос, как подсчитать всего количество лет? Спасибо!

Comment: такое уравнение мне не позубам)

Comment: это уравнение максимум для 7 класса общеобразовательной школы. В добавок, я его уже решил. Вам нужно только написать код. функция ln (логарифм) уже есть в php.

Comment: с годами не выходит                       FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) on line number 17

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы узнать сколько потребовалось лет, из $age вычитайте 16

```
if ($vsego > 1000000) {
    echo "Ура лям в банке. Всего потребовалось " . ($age - 16) . " лет<br/>";
    break;
}
```

Comment: элегантно) спасибо большое! но дает ошибку(

Comment: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) on line number 18